# Return a value from a insert statement

Tags: vb.net, oracle, asp.net-2.0

Working with an Oracle 9i database from an ASP.NET 2.0 (VB) application using OLEDB.  Is there a way to have an insert statement return a value?  I have a sequence set up to number entries as they go into the database, but I need that value to come back after the insert so I can do some manipulation to the set I just entered in the code-behind VB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some possibilities:

1) Use the RETURNING clause:

```
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename) VALUES (emp_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ANDREWS')
RETURNING empno INTO :variable;
```

2) Use the sequence CURRVAL:

```
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename) VALUES (emp_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ANDREWS');
SELECT emp_seq.CURRVAL INTO :variable FROM DUAL;
```

CURRVAL returns the last sequence value generated by your session.

Comment: Hi Tony, Is this applicable for SQL Server also. I need the same thing for SQL Server 2008 R2 .

Comment: @Sujay, sorry I don't know SQL Server but see http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/83675-return-primary-key-insert-statement

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am not looking for a stored procedure.

Comment: Sujay: This seems to work at least for me as a single statement (from one of the responses in that article). INSERT INTO MyTable (MyData) VALUES(1) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Answer (score 2):

Oracle seem to have a keywod called "returning" which can return a given column of the inserted row, however that might require you to set the "autoincrement" field manually by invoking the next value in your sequence.

Check this discussion about it:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=354998

However, you can always select the current sequence-number in a second query, sort of like MySQLs `last_insert_id()`

Answer (score 0):

If this value is the key the database creates, you've ran into a good example why you should use UUIDs as your table key, and generate them in code.

This method will give you faster performance in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

First use a **SELECT** statement to get the next sequence.  You may use [the Oracle dual table](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/dual.html) to do this.

```
SELECT my_seq.nextval FROM dual
```

Use the sequence that you retrieved in subsequent **INSERT** statements.

```
INSERT ...
INSERT ...
```