# Returning a value from an INSERT statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Database : SQL Server 2008

Is there a way to have an insert statement return a value in SQL Server,

There is a similar question in

[Return a value from a insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270695/return-a-value-from-a-insert-statement) , which talks about ORACLE .

I don't work with databases much, and not aware of ORACLE/SQL Server much, so sorry to ask it all over again.

For simplicity let me provide a small example :

The table `EmpDetails` has `EmpiD` and `EmpName`. The value of `EmpID` is autogenerated by the database.

```
INSERT INTO EMPDETAILS VALUES("John")
```

Now I want to get the value of `EmpID` associated with John

I don't want a stored procedure, I want a SQL statement only .

Comment: I wonder why you are so adamant about not wanting a stored procedure and returning `scope_identity()`.

Comment: @JonH I am not being adamant :-) The situation requires me to use a SQL statment. But feel free to post the SP too as a sidenot , maybe it might help me/others later.

Comment: No reason to post one, it would be a duplicate in the SO database, do a search plenty of articles / questions about it directly on this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes - you can use the little known and little used [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) in your INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(col1, col2, col3, ...., ColN)
OUTPUT Inserted.Col1, Inserted.Col5, Inserted.ColN
VALUES(val1, val2, val3, ....., valN)
```

This returns a normal set of data, that you can deal with as you need to.

As the MSDN docs show, you can also send the OUTPUT values into e.g. a table variable or temp table for later use, if you need to.

To answer your updated question, use this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPDETAILS(EmpName)
OUTPUT Inserted.EmpID
VALUES("John")
```

Comment: @JonH: yes, indeed - it's one of those "hidden gems" that a lot of developers overlook and don't know about...

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. I have updated my question, can you please provide me a sql statement for the EmpDetails table.

Comment: @Sujay Ghosh `OUTPUT Inserted.ID`

Comment: Is there a similar method for sqlite3?