# reusing result of SELECT statement within a CASE statement sqllite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I want to create an SQL statement (using sqllite.. so I can't use functions, IF statements etc..) that reuses the result of a select statement.. this is what it currently looks like

```
INSERT INTO search_email(many_fields, threadid) VALUES ('many_fields',
    CASE 
    WHEN
            (
                (SELECT COUNT(tableX.threadid) %threadIDquery% 
                ) > 0
            )
    THEN

                (SELECT tableX.threadid %threadIDquery% LIMIT 1)

    ELSE 
            0
    END
)
```

I want to reuse the result of first select instead of having to make another (almost identical) select statement.

**update:** for those wondering what i'm trying to do.. here is the full version of the query:

```
INSERT INTO search_email(meta, subject, body, sender, tos, ccs, folder, threadid) VALUES ('meta1','subject1','body1','sender1', 'tos1',' ccs1','folder1',
    CASE 
    WHEN
            (
                (SELECT COUNT(search_email.threadID) FROM search_email 
                                                            WHERE search_email.subject MATCH '%query%'  AND 
                                                            (
                                                                (search_email.sender = '%sender' AND search_email.tos = '%receiver%')
                                                                OR 
                                                                (search_email.sender = '%receiver%' AND search_email.tos = '%sender%')
                                                            )
                ) > 0
            )
    THEN

            (SELECT search_email.threadID FROM search_email 
                                                        WHERE search_email.subject MATCH '%query%'  AND 
                                                        (
                                                            (search_email.sender = '%sender%' AND search_email.tos = '%receiver%')
                                                            OR 
                                                            (search_email.sender = '%receiver%' AND search_email.tos = '%sender%')
                                                        )  LIMIT 1
            )

    ELSE 
            //generate new thread ID
    END
)
```

basically i'm trying to find out if an email thread already exists for an incoming email.. so i check if the subject matches and if it does, i check to see if the sender and receiver of the email match (in either direction).. if the email thread exists i just insert the same email threadID, else i generate a new threadID

**update 2:**just to clarify, I'm looking for a way to save the sqllite compiler from making the same search twice.. rather than simply saving on typing (or making it more readable etc)

**update 3:** i was wondering if there was a way for this statement to return the generated threadID iff the threadID was retrieved from the dbase, rather than generated.. you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14056652/766570)

Comment: What is this trying to do?  I can see how your answer manages to parse the data, but I don't think it is actually doing what you need.

Comment: updated question to address your comment

Comment: is it SQL Server or SQLite? You are aware that even if you do manage to save the typing of the query twice, the query will be run twice and yield potentially different results, right?

Comment: SQLlite.. um.. well i'm obviously not interested in saving the typing.. i was hoping for something less expensive.. there must be a way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative way of structuring the query:

```
INSERT INTO search_email(meta, subject, body, sender, tos, ccs, folder, threadid)
    SELECT 'meta1', 'subject1', 'body1', 'sender1', 'tos1', 'ccs1', 'folder1',
            coalesce((SELECT search_email.threadID
                      FROM search_email 
                      WHERE search_email.subject MATCH '%query%' AND 
                            ((search_email.sender = '%sender%' AND search_email.tos = '%receiver%') OR
                             (search_email.sender = '%receiver%' AND search_email.tos = '%sender%')
                            )
                      LIMIT 1
                     ),
                     <generate new thread id here>
                    )
```

This is using a `select` instead of `values`.  It gets the thread id that matches the conditions, or NULL if none match.  The second clause of the `coalesce` is then run when the first is NULL.  You can generate the new id there.

I do have a problem with this approach.  To me, it seems that you should have a Thread table that manages the threads.  The ThreadId should be an autoincremented id in this table.  The emails table can then reference this id.  In other words, I think the data model needs to be thought out in more detail.

The following query will not query work, but it gives the idea of moving the thread to the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO search_email(meta, subject, body, sender, tos, ccs, folder, threadid)
    SELECT 'meta1', 'subject1', 'body1', 'sender1', 'tos1', 'ccs1', 'folder1',
            coalesce(t.threadID,
                     <generate new thread id here>
                    )
    from (SELECT search_email.threadID
          FROM search_email 
          WHERE search_email.subject MATCH '%query%' AND 
                ((search_email.sender = '%sender%' AND search_email.tos = '%receiver%') OR
                 (search_email.sender = '%receiver%' AND search_email.tos = '%sender%')
                )
          LIMIT 1
         ) t
```

The reason it will not work is because the `from` clause will return no rows rather than 1 row with a NULL value.  So, to get what you want, you can use:

```
    from (SELECT search_email.threadID
          FROM search_email 
          WHERE search_email.subject MATCH '%query%' AND 
                ((search_email.sender = '%sender%' AND search_email.tos = '%receiver%') OR
                 (search_email.sender = '%receiver%' AND search_email.tos = '%sender%')
                )
          union all
          select NULL
          order by (case when threadId is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc
          LIMIT 1
         ) t
```

This ensures that a NULL value is returned when there is no thread.

Comment: *sigh*.. I know what you mean.. [ideally speaking](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) i wouldn't be using databases at all to solve this problem (ie email threading).. this is what happens when you have a client who things they're clever when they keep on cutting development time.. thanks though!

Comment: oright it works! right answer awarded.. +1 b/c you seem like a good guy

Comment: follow up question: is there a way to have this sql statement return the threadID only if it was fetched from the table.. rather than generated?

Comment: Yes.  You have to put the inner `SELECT` statement in a subquery so it can return the additional information.  With the structure of the subquery only returning one value it would be hard.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. I thought the inner select statement *is* a subquery.. I just don't see how its result would bubble out of this insert statement. If you don't mind.. Can you add to your answer above an example that illustrates your point?

Comment: oh excellent! thanks for the edit.. I'll update the original question to include the follow up question

Comment: after taking a long look at your second answer.. i can't see how this insert statement will return a result.. looking at the web.. i see that the [only way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825005/returning-a-value-from-an-insert-statement-in-sql-server-2008) one can do that is via an OUTPUT parameter (something that sqllite doesn't support) or a trigger.. how does your above answer go around that?

Comment: i get the error: 
`1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set` which makes sense b/c the subquery will return something under threadID column.. and the order by clause doesn't have threadID in it.. I tried putting just threadID in the order by clause.. and it worked in the sense that it succeeded in adding stuff.. but the final result didn't return anything unfortunately (ie as a final result to the insert statement)

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102104/how-to-convert-an-sqllite-statement-from-to-match-instead) is a follow up question as well for those interested

Comment: hey Gordon.. apparently using this statement causes some [memory management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462951/ios-sqlite3-statement-causing-memory-problems-with-sqlite-transient) problems when used in objective-c..