# How to get the last created ID in SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I created a table called participant composed by participant_ID (which is the primary key and is identity[has an auto-value]) and session_ID (which is a foreign key).

When I create a new participant, I would like to store its participant_ID.

I have the following code, but I get the following message error: 'Syntax problem near returning'

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Serve=:xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx')
cur = connection.cursor()
pID = cur.execute('INSERT INTO participant(sessions_ID) VALUES (40) RETURNING participant_ID')
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate / related - [Returning a value from an INSERT statement in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825005/returning-a-value-from-an-insert-statement-in-sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 11):

This is a really, really old post, I know - but I had the same question and came upon it. I got mine working and thought I would share for those that stumble here as I have. Please be kind, this was my first pass at the code. It isn't pretty, but it should get you started.

```
def exec_query(self, query_type, query):
    # query_type: This is an enumumeration defining the CRUD operation of the query.

    # Note, the native client (11.0) might change with time and Windows updates)
    # Note, the driver varlue would normally go in a constant, I put it here just for clarity
    with pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; ' + self.cnx_str) as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)

        if query_type is QueryType.create:
            try:
                cursor.execute("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                seed_id = row[0]
            except AttributeError:
                seed_id = 0
            cursor.commit()
            return seed_id

        # ... Additional code for non 'create' operations
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it doesn't explain where `query_type` and `QueryType` come from.

Comment: @DataHerder; I can see how that could be confusing -- its just an enumeration that I created to pass to my method. It can be ignored, the important part is the code inside the create 'if' statement.

Comment: I had this error no results.  Previous SQL was not a query. I m using a stored procedure. How can I get the id identity

Answer (score 9):

You can do it in 2 ways

1. `select SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - this is preferred as it's limited by scope to identity you created.
2. `select @@IDENTITY` - this is the last identity that was created regardless of the scope (e.g. a trigger can create additional identities).

See more in here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: I WROTE pID = cur.execute("SEELECT @@Identity") after the previous query, but I get the following: <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x03AFEBB8> ...How could I get the value of the ID?

Comment: Do you have double EE in select?

Comment: Does your table has Identity column.?

Answer (score 0):

Please try `SELECT @@Identity` after insert query this will return Primary key Identity column value for current connection.

Comment: I WROTE pID = cur.execute("SELECT @@Identity") after the previous query, but I get the following: <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x03AFEBB8>

Comment: you have to append ".fetchone()"

Comment: I have to add `[0]` and make it as int `int(self.dbcon.execute("SELECT @@IDENTITY as id").fetchone()[0])` .

Comment: You can cast it to Int or long based on your database field datatype to match it with your code variable type