# How to return identity value from sqldatasource.insert() in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I want to return id from insert.
I found solution it's use select scope_identify.
But I want example for my code.

```
sqlDatasource ds = new sqlDatasource();
ds.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Product (Name) VALUES (@Name)";
ds.InsertParameters.Add("@Name", txtName.text);
ds.Insert();
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer, which is difficult to find, is here: [SQLDataSourceIdentity Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209298/return-scope-identity-using-sqldatasource-in-code-behind)

Which refers user here: [Retrieving the Just-Inserted ID of an IDENTITY Column Using a SqlDataSource Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304124645/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100108-1.aspx)

Step 1 - add an Output Parameter

```
 <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="NewID" Type="Int32" />
```

Step 2 - Add additional statement after insert command in SqlDataSource InsertCommand

```
SELECT @NewID=Scope_Identity()
```

Step 3 - Retrieve inserted value in SqlDataSource_Inserted event handler

```
e.command.Parameters("@NewID").value.tostring
```

Answer (score 1):

An `INSERT` statement cannot return anything. You have to execute as `SELECT` to get the scope identity. If you want to execute it all in one statement, you cannot do it using [SqlDataSource.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As the documentation says, it returns an `int` counting the rows affected by the statement.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Product (Name) VALUES (@Name);Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();;";
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
connection.Open();
string NewID= sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: thank you very much. but i want to use with sqlDatasource.Insert(); Is there posible ?

Answer (score 1):

Having not found an acceptable answer after searching the internet for 3 days; this is what works:

Using an example of inserting a user name and returning an Id...

Create a stored procedure similar to this:

```
create procedure Users_Insert 
      @UserName varchar(25) 
     ,@UserId int = null output
as

insert into Users (UserName) values (@UserName)

select @UserId = scope_identity();

return @UserId;
```

Now in your aspx page configure your SqlDataSource as such:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsUsers" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnection %>"
        InsertCommand="Users_Insert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" OnInserted="dsUsers_Inserted">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUserName" Name="UserName" Type="String" PropertyName="Text" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Int32" Direction="ReturnValue" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

*Note the OnInserted event is wired up.*

Now, in your code behind, perhaps in a Save button click event, call the insert method:

```
 dsUsers.Insert();
```

And finally, in the dsUsers_Inserted method that we previously wired up, get the identity:

```
protected void dsUsers_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
     int userId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value);
}
```

Hope this helps at least one person.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with oracle, [RETURNING INTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270695/return-a-value-from-a-insert-statement) might be what you are looking for. It allows you to save your new id in an output variable. I have only used it with `ExecuteNonQuery()` though, so it might not work with `Insert()`

If you are working with sql developer, [OUTPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825005/returning-a-value-from-an-insert-statement-in-sql-server-2008) might help, though I have not used that one myself yet.