# Return scope identity using sqldatasource in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I'm doing an insert into the db from codebehind with a sqldatasource in the following way.

```
SqlDataSource13.InsertParameters["name"].DefaultValue = ufn;
            SqlDataSource13.InsertParameters["mime_type"].DefaultValue = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
            SqlDataSource13.InsertParameters["size"].DefaultValue = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength.ToString();
            SqlDataSource13.InsertParameters["extension"].DefaultValue = "";
            SqlDataSource13.InsertParameters["date"].DefaultValue = dt.ToShortDateString();
            SqlDataSource13.InsertParameters["type"].DefaultValue = ddlDocType.SelectedValue;
            SqlDataSource13.InsertParameters["description"].DefaultValue = tbDescription.Text;
            SqlDataSource13.Insert();
```

This is working fine. However I need to now get the insert id. I added select scope_identity to the end of the insert query. and the parameter to the insertparameters with direction=ouput.

```
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
<asp:Parameter Name="id" Direction="Output" />
```

however I need to figure out how to get the output parameter with the setup i have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make things easier on myself I switched to a linq to sql query.

```
tableDataContext tdc = new tableDataContext();
doc d = new doc();
d.dpi = qs;
d.dn = ufn;
etc...
tdc.docs.InsertOnSubmit(d);
tdc.SubmitChanges();

// get current row insert id
int dID = d.id;
```

So now I have the recently inserted doc id to use.
Easy.

Thanks to whoever wrote this [example](http://imaginekitty.com/576/scope_identity-with-linq/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void SqlDataSource13_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    string sID = e.Command.Parameters["@Identity"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Taken from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304124645/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100108-1.aspx) (not C# but the idea is there)

Comment: I knew about that one. however I wanted to use it with what I was doing above. In the end I changed to a linq query.